# Why is Tensorflow not executing statements in tf.Session() in correct order?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

seems to be a long post but most of it is output of the print().
I am using a custom generator function to feed my keras `.fit_generator()` function with data. In my generator function I simply do some data augmentation. At the end of this function I open a `tf.Session()` to finally yield batches of data.

```
def iAmTheCustomGeneratorFunction(...):
    ... data augemenation...
    next_batch = iterator.get_next()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        count = 0
        while True:
            try:
                features1, features2, labels = sess.run(next_batch)             
                print('\n\n   I am a print before yield. ' + str(count))
                yield [features1, features2], labels
                print('   I am a print behind yield. ' + str(count))
                count = count +1
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print('end of the dataset')
                break
```

When I run the code following problems arise. I wrote the question behind the output as comments (see below). 
I get as output in the console:

```
Epoch 1/1    
I am a print before yield. Index: 0
I am a print behind yield. Index: 0
...
I am a print before yield. Index: 9
I am a print behind yield. Index: 9 
# (1) Why does it loop 10 times before it starts with calculating loss/accuracy

...
# -> This is what the output should look like
I am a print before yield. Index: 10
1/58 [......]- ETA: 12:22 - loss: 20.6840 - acc: 0.20
I am a print behind yield. Index: 10

...

I am a print before yield. Index: 56
47/58 [......]- ETA: 11:00 - loss: 18.6840 - acc: 0.42
I am a print behind yield. Index: 56

# (2) Why suddenly the "I am print before/behind yield" is missing?
48/58 [......]- ETA: 10:22 - loss: 16.6840 - acc: 0.53 
...
52/58 [......]- ETA: 9:22 - loss: 15.6840 - acc: 0.54


# (3) Why suddenly information about accuracy/loss is missing?
I am a print before yield. Index: 57 
I am a print behind yield. Index: 57
...
I am a print before yield. Index: 61
I am a print behind yield. Index: 61
...

# -> Now it works as usual
I am a print before yield. Index: 62
53/58 [......]- ETA: 08:22 - loss: 14.6840 - acc: 0.55
I am a print behind yield. Index: 62

...
I am a print before yield. Index: 66
57/58 [......]- ETA: 07:22 - loss: 12.6840 - acc: 0.58
I am a print behind yield. Index: 66

I am a print before yield. Index: 67
# -> Here arises the Exception: 
Duplicate node name in graph: tensors_1/component_0' and IndexError pop from empty list`
```

What I do not get is why does tensorflow does not print everything in the right order and also starts at index 10 with the first calculation of loss and accuracy (see above). This `pop from empty list exception` results in my opinion from a this mess. ALso it dioes not finish the first epoch correctly.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

> (1) Why does it loop 10 times before it starts with calculating loss/accuracy

From the documentation for `fit_generator`

- max_queue_size: Integer. Maximum size for the generator queue. If unspecified, max_queue_size will default to 10.

> (2) Why suddenly the "I am print before/behind yield" is missing?

It could be related to the fact that the generator and the training loop are executed in different threads. That could cause messages to appear in different orders.

- workers: Integer. Maximum number of processes to spin up when using process-based threading. If unspecified, workers will default to 1. If 0, will execute the generator on the main thread.

> -> Here arises the Exception: 
>   Duplicate node name in graph: tensors_1/component_0' and IndexError pop from empty list`

This seems related to the tf operations you are using in the generator. Is it possible for you to do this as pre-processing ?. i.e. Simply create a new dataset that doesn't depend on tensorflow APIs to read.

Also a suggestion in terms of troubleshooting methodology: I find it useful to test the generator independently from the model.

Once can test the data generator, for instance by running a full run of the generator, not feeding to any model, just making sure that the array shapes that it generates are correct. Specially the last batch.

And I believe that it is always useful to test the model by feeding it a single batch (or even a single example) and make sure that all the shapes checkout correctly on `fit`.

Comment: I think you are right with your intuition where the exception arises:
This exception arises in the transition from training to validation step. In the following some observations about the exception:
When I use (just for testing) my actual validation data for training and the actual training data for validation it also trains correctly until the transition to the validation step after the first epoch. Next observation: Also if I run the `fit_generator()` function without validation (`validation_data=None`) everything is working fine and no exception does arise.

Comment: Next observation: The code line where it fails is in the generator function while creating a tensor via `tensor_one = tf.data.Dataset.get_tensor_slices(AlistOfTensors)`. So here the `pop from empty list`arises but I do not understand why? Is there any inference you can see between the exception and the oberservations? The data seems to be ok it is anthing in ths transition to the validation

Comment: From your description it sounds as if there is a conflict between the tensors/graph/session used by the generator instance that generates the train samples vs the instance that generates the validation samples. I never understood the myriad of hidden global variables used by tensorflow but you may be able to experiment with trying to set a context ```with session: with graph: with variable_scope``` such that the scopes are different for train and validation..